# Auto Capitalize ONLY the First Letter of Each Word in an Input Field

Tags: javascript

I have multiple input fields that obtain a city. I would like **while the user is imputing the city name** that the first letter **of each word** to auto capitalize, while **the rest of the letters are forced lower case**.

**NOTE:** Because of my requirements, the CSS `text-transform` property won't work because it only modifies the first letter of the words - - if the user types capital letters beyond the first letter, that won't adjust it.

So far i have this JavaScript:

```
function forceLower(strInput) {
  strInput.value=strInput.value.toLowerCase();
}
```

Which is successfully converting the entire input to lowercase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See comments inline for details:

```js
// Get a reference to the input and wire it up to an input event handler that
// calls the fixer function
document.getElementById("txtTest").addEventListener("input", forceLower);

// Event handling functions are automatically passed a reference to the
// event that triggered them as the first argument (evt)
function forceLower(evt) {
  // Get an array of all the words (in all lower case)
  var words = evt.target.value.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/g);
  
  // Loop through the array and replace the first letter with a cap
  var newWords = words.map(function(element){   
    // As long as we're not dealing with an empty array element, return the first letter
    // of the word, converted to upper case and add the rest of the letters from this word.
    // Return the final word to a new array
    return element !== "" ?  element[0].toUpperCase() + element.substr(1, element.length) : "";
  });
  
 // Replace the original value with the updated array of capitalized words.
 evt.target.value = newWords.join(" "); 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtTest">
```

Comment: GREAT JOB @Scott Marcus, Great details and works perfectly. Great job

Comment: This latest iteration is throwing the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

Comment: its throwing on page load

Comment: @Charles You've probably added this code BEFORE the rest of the DOM was loaded. Put your script at the BOTTOM of the page, just before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: @MattiaPontonio Please do not ever edit someone else's answer because you want to show the code in a more/less optimized way. I take great care in the way I structure my answers and which code I choose to show for the solution. Yes, the solution could be optimized, but generally people asking these kinds of simple questions need more easily understandable answers, not optimized code. And, of course, any good programmer knows that you solve the problem first and optimized the code later. If you'd like to show optimized code, add your own answer.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Is there a way to add exceptions to this code, so that words like "of" or "and" don't be capitalized?

Answer (score 4):

you can use css for this text-transform: capitalize

```js
function firstCap(str){
  var returnVar='';
  var strSplit=str.split(' ');
 for(var i=0;i<strSplit.length;i++){
 returnVar=returnVar+strSplit[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+strSplit[i].substring(1).toLowerCase() +' ';
  }
return returnVar
}
```

```css
div , input {text-transform: capitalize;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> this is only the first lettter</div>
<input type="text"/>
```

Comment: This won't lowercase the rest of the letters.

Comment: Yes that solves the capitol problem however it still allows me to capitalize the remainder of the string.

Comment: This does not solve the problem of capital letters AFTER the first letter being converted to lower-case.