# First letter of first word in a sentence to uppercase

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using `style="text-transform:capitalize"` so the get the first letter of an word to uppercase.
But now I am facing the problem that each 1st letter of each word is converted to uppercase. How to prevent this?

So `helle new world` becomes `Hello new world`

Original code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="bedrijfsnaam" name="bedrijfsnaam" value="" style="text-transform:capitalize">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto Capitalize ONLY the First Letter of Each Word in an Input Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41048336/auto-capitalize-only-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-an-input-field)

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41048336/auto-capitalize-only-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-an-input-field which already has an excellent answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about pure CSS solution, but this simple js could help:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="bedrijfsnaam" name="bedrijfsnaam" value="">

field=document.getElementById('bedrijfsnaam');

field.onkeyup = function(){
str=this.value;
this.value=str[0].toUpperCase()+str.slice(1,str.length);

};
```

Snippet:

```js
field=document.getElementById('bedrijfsnaam');

field.onkeyup = function(){
str=this.value;
this.value=str[0].toUpperCase()+str.slice(1,str.length);

};
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="bedrijfsnaam" name="bedrijfsnaam" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capitalize the first letter of the #bedrijfsnaam element by using the pseudo-element `:first-letter`

```
 #bedrijfsnaam:first-letter{
      text-transform: capitalize; 
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
#bedrijfsnaam {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

#bedrijfsnaam:first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('input').keypress(function(){
                var $this = $(this),
                val = $this.val();
                val = val.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + val.substr(1);
                $this.val(val);
            });
        });

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <input type='text' name='name' class='name' placeholder='Enter your name here'/>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#bedrijfsnaam::first-letter,
#bedrijfsnaam:first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

**Explanation:**

- Old browsers cannot understand `::first-letter` (with 2 double colon), but can understand `:first-letter` (with 1 double colon). So the above code should work with most browsers.
- We can't apply `::first-letter` directly to the HTML element's style because it requires **state** (which is `::first-letter`)

Answer (score 0):

```
selector::first-letter:{
text-transform: uppercase
}
```

The `::first-letter` CSS pseudo-element applies styles to the first letter of the first line of a block-level element, but only when not preceded by other content (such as images or inline tables).
[Style First Letter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter)