# how to capitalize every first letter with none before an apostrophe but with one after in javascript

Tags: javascript, capitalize

In javascript, I need to capitalize each first letter of words in a string (proper name) but not when before an apostrophe such as this example :

from henri d'oriona --> Henry d'Oriona

All I can get is something like Henry D'oriona or best case Henry D'Oriona.

Thanks for your help

Jacques

Comment: And what did you try till now?

Comment: [This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41048336/auto-capitalize-only-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-an-input-field/41048432#41048432), but it doesn't take apostrophes into account. Shouldn't be too hard to adapt.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method with a regular expression to produce a one-liner solution.

Note that `String.replace` can accept a function for its second argument which can be used to loop through the matches and modify them as necessary.

```js
const specialCapitalize = 
 str => str.replace(/(\w[^\'])+/gi, word => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1));

console.log(specialCapitalize("henri d'oriona some other words"))
```

The regular expression `/(\w[^\'])+/` is made up of a word character which is not followed by an apostrophe.

Answer (score 0):

First case but to great was:
toTitleCase('henri d'oriona')

returns Henri D'orina
        function toTitleCase(str) {

```
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g,
    function(txt) {
            return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    }
    );
```

}

and best case scenario returning "Henri D'Oriona"

```
    function toProperCase(s) {
    return s.toLowerCase().replace( /\b((m)(a?c))?(\w)/g,
            function($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) { if($2){return $3.toUpperCase()+$4+$5.toUpperCase();}
    return $1.toUpperCase(); });
```

}

Comment: Neither of those produce the preferred results of "Henri d'Orina"

Answer (score 0):

Create a function which will make the first letter upperCase called `capitalize`. 
After that, split the string by empty space and traverse the array obtained.

For each element from the resulted array apply `capitalize` :

`let upperCase = capitalize(word);`

Then join the values from array into one string.

```js
const capitalize = (s) => {

  if (typeof s !== 'string') return ''
  let capitalWord = '';

  if (s.includes("d'")) {

    let nameAfterSpecialChar = s.split("d'")[1];
    let capitalName = nameAfterSpecialChar.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + nameAfterSpecialChar.slice(1)
    capitalWord = "d'" + capitalName

  } else {
    capitalWord = s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1)
  }

  return capitalWord;
}

const makeNameWithCapital = (name) => { 
  var wordsList = name.split(" ");
  let arrOfNames = []

  for (let word of wordsList) {
    let upperCase = capitalize(word);
    arrOfNames.push(upperCase);
  }

  let nameWithUpper = arrOfNames.join(" ");
  console.log(nameWithUpper)
  
  return nameWithUpper;
}

const nameUnparsed= "henri d'oriona "
const nameUnparsed1 = "henri d'oriona d'example test"

makeNameWithCapital(nameUnparsed)
makeNameWithCapital(nameUnparsed1)
```

It's not the best solution from performance point of view, but you can use it as a start.